# django - Creating a radio select with select box options

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I want to create a set of radio options that look like so:

[image: Radio options which are widgets]

The non-standard part is that selecting the first or second radio button option requires the user to further specify information from a select box.

How do I do this with a django form? Based on what I see in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField) you can pass a Choices 2-tuple with only strings as the human-readable values, I need the ability to pass a widget plus a label. I am rendering the form via django-crispy-forms in the template (i.e. all my template has is `{% crispy form %}`), so I would prefer a solution that doesn't require any template-side manipulation.

Thanks!

Comment: The thing is, even if you could pass a widget to the choices tuple, to what model field would django relate the values in the spinners? Have you thought about dropping the controls in the form, positioning them with CSS and then using javascript to make them enabled or disabled?

Comment: @Mariano This form is not directly tied to a model (i.e. not a ModelForm, just a form). What do you mean by "dropping the controls"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant just displaying them in html, then using CSS to position them, and JS to control their behavior. The problem with this is that it's a template-side (or more of a client side) manipulation, and as such is not really reusable. What you wanted, defining your custom widget, is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget) as a way of creating widgets composed of other widgets. There are also some implementations listed, so you could always check them out and follow by example.

Comment: Also, even though this isn't tied to a model, you should think about the server side representation of the data. For example, do you have only one choice field with 3 possible values? And then just one "additional value" text field? Or do you have three different fields and only one of them can be populated at a time? To better model this I'd think about how to handle the POST data coming from the server.

Comment: thanks @Mariano, I ended up simplifying and just conditionally enabling and disabling a seperate listbox as you first suggested.

Answer (score -1):

in forms.py

```
CHOICES = (('0', 'option1',), ('1', 'option2',), ('2', 'option3',))
```

class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
options = forms.ChoiceField(initial=0, widget = forms.RadioSelect(renderer = HorizontalRadioRenderer), choices=OPTIONS)
```

Comment: Thanks @gangakvp, but I think your answer missed the point. How do I make option1, option2, etc. form inputs (i.e. a select box) instead of strings?

Comment: every one didnt post a to z.u only understand that, u give choice list for option 1, and another choice list for option2.